# What is the difference between 2 sentences in meaning?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between 2 sentences in meaning?

> 1. An unhealthy instant food contains lots of unhealthy preservatives.
> 2. Instant food, which contains many preservatives, is unhealthy.

Comment: Your question would be better if you described the research you have already done in order to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 makes a claim about **unhealthy instant food**. It says nothing about ***healthy* instant food**. So the claim is limited.

#2 makes a claim about **instant food** in general. If we exclude the words between the commas, it looks like this:

> Instant food is unhealthy.

So the claim is about all instant food.

Perhaps you do not understand the significance of the commas. They signal to a reader that the information between them is nonrestrictive. That is, it does not limit the focus to a special kind of **instant food**. Rather, it claims that ALL instant food contains many preservatives.

If you wish to use a relative clause to limit the focus, you must remove the commas:

> Instant food which contains many preservatives is unhealthy.

The meaning is now nearly the same as #1. The sentence claims that *only* the kind of **instant food** that **contains preservatives** is **unhealthy.**

Some authorities advise us to use **that** instead of **which** in such a sentence:

> Instant food that contains many preservatives is unhealthy.

This is not a rule, as some people believe, but it is reasonable advice.